# Facebook Graph API: GET /feed without privacy "SELF"

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

how do I have to structure API request (preferably in the JavaScript API version of Graph) to **GET** everything in the **/feed** which **does not have privacy** value set to **"SELF"**?

so far I've only managed to fetch /feed objects with privacy objects in them, to be able to process them on the client - which I do not want to do since the API limits are quickly and unnecessarily consumed.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do I have to structure API request (preferably in the JavaScript API version of Graph) to GET everything in the /feed which does not have privacy value set to "SELF"?

There is no way to achieve that kind of filtering; you will have to do it on your end.

> so far I've only managed to fetch /feed objects with privacy objects in them, to be able to process them on the client - which I do not want to do since the API limits are quickly and unnecessarily consumed.

Facebook's argument for not providing more filtering and sorting capabilities is that it is just detrimental to performance - lessons learned from FQL times. (Source: Facebook engineers in a Q&A session.)

---

So you have no other choice than to consider your app the cloud computing service that this gets outsourced to in this instance ;-)